# Como otimizar busca de parâmetros no r?

Tags: r, otimização

Estou há horas esperando meu código terminar de rodar. Imagino que deve haver uma forma mais inteligente de fazer isso, afinal não preciso visitar todos os pontos quando tenho uma função monótona ao redor de um ponto de mínimo.

Meu problema está relacionada a teoria das filas, tenho o tempo médio na fila, o `c` e a taxa de saída.

```
  lambda    <-seq(0,ceiling(mu*PDV),0.0001)
  n.lambda<-seq_along(lambda)
  diferenca <-NULL
  diferenca1<-300
  for (i in n.lambda) {
    try(wq<-queueing::QueueingModel(
      queueing::NewInput.MMC(lambda=lambda[i], mu=mu, c=PDV))$Wq, silent = TRUE)
    if(is.na(wq)) next
    diferenca<-(wq-Wq)^2
    if(diferenca<diferenca1){
      lambdaWin <-lambda[i]
    }

    diferenca1<-diferenca
  }
```

Alguma sugestão de como melhorá-lo?

Comment: Se entendi bem, o teu problema é encontrar o ponto de mínimo de uma função, correto? Há algum motivo para não utilizar a função `optim` do `R`? Acredito que se tu editar a pergunta com alguma `função_de_interesse`, alguém aqui vai ser capaz de te ajudar a implementar uma solução utilizando `optim`.

Comment: É que meu problema é com teoria da fila.
```queueing::QueueingModel(
      queueing::NewInput.MMC(lambda=lambda[i], mu=mu, c=PDV))$Lq```
Tenho o comprimento da fila é quero saber o lambda que retornaria isso.

Comment: Aí eu não vou poder ajudar. Não é um assunto que domino.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Obrigado. Eu tinha ouvido falar de códigos que particionavam sucessivamente o domínio para buscar pontos de mínimos.